# Tracking ads with Piwik analytic tool

Tags: web-analytics, matomo

I have this link for each Ad(`ad_id` is dynamic):

index.php/view/[ad_id]

How can I track each Ad with Piwik? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

By default Piwik will track the pages and group them by directory in the Page Titles reports. You may also use track them using "page" scope custom variables, see: http://piwik.org/docs/custom-variables/

Comment: So Goal is not suitable for this mean?